# AmbiguousMethodCallException in Apache Camel custom Component

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to write my own Component for Apache Camel. It works fine when I put parameters in the URI. When I give no parameters it throws an AmbiguousMethodCallException. Why does this happen?

This works:

```
from("file:in/csv?noop=true")
    .to("cvsToXml:?delimiterChar=;")
    .to("file:out/csv");
```

This does not:

```
from("file:in/csv?noop=true")
    .to("cvsToXml")
    .to("file:out/csv");
```

The error:

```
org.apache.camel.component.bean.AmbiguousMethodCallException: Ambiguous method invocations possible: [public org.apache.camel.Endpoint org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception, public org.apache.camel.EndpointConfiguration org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createConfiguration(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception]. Exchange[Message: Header1;Header2;Header3;Header4;Header5;Header6;Header7;Header8;Header9;Header10 Value1_1;Value2_1;Value3_1;Value4_1;Value5_1;Value6_1;Value7_1;Value8_1;Value9_1;Value10_1 Value1_2;Value2_2;Value3_2;Value4_2;Value5_2;Value6_2;Value7_2;Value8_2;Value9_2;Value10_2 Value1_3;Value2_3;Value3_3;Value4_3;Value5_3;Value6_3;Value7_3;Value8_3;Value9_3;Value10_3 Value1_4;Value2_4;Value3_4;Value4_4;Value5_4;Value6_4;Value7_4;Value8_4;Value9_4;Value10_4 Value1_5;Value2_5;Value3_5;Value4_5;Value5_5;Value6_5;Value7_5;Value8_5;Value9_5;Value10_5 Value1_6;Value2_6;Value3_6;Value4_6;Value5_6;Value6_6;Value7_6;Value8_6;Value9_6;Value10_6 Value1_7;Value2_7;Value3_7;Value4_7;Value5_7;Value6_7;Value7_7;Value8_7;Value9_7;Value10_7 Value1_8;Value2_8;Value3_8;Value4_8;Value5_8;Value6_8;Value7_8;Value8_8;Value9_8;Value10_8 Value1_9;Value2_9;Value3_9;Value4_9;Value5_9;Value6_9;Value7_9;Value8_9;Value9_9;Value10_9 Value1_10;Value2_10;Value3_10;Value4_10;Value5_10;Value6_10;Value7_10;Value8_10;Value9_10;Value10_10... [Body clipped after 1000 chars, total length is 2012]]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInfo.chooseBestPossibleMethodInfo(BeanInfo.java:745)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInfo.chooseMethodWithMatchingBody(BeanInfo.java:676)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInfo.chooseMethod(BeanInfo.java:544)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInfo.createInvocation(BeanInfo.java:273)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInfo.createInvocation(BeanInfo.java:180)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:149)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:423)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:211)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:114)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line gives you a big clue as to what is going wrong. (Reformatted to enhance readability)

```
org.apache.camel.component.bean.AmbiguousMethodCallException: Ambiguous method invocations possible: 
public org.apache.camel.Endpoint 
org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
public org.apache.camel.EndpointConfiguration 
org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createConfiguration(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
```

The arguments you are passing in can be applied to more than one method.
Keyword **Ambiguous**

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, this I see too. But both classes are camel-core methods. Not from my component (csvToXml). Ok, my component extends from DefaultComponent, but how can i solve this Problem?

Comment: Go ahead and give this a read, let me know if it helps you: http://camel.apache.org/writing-components.html

Comment: I know the Document, I read it more than one time but there are always parameters in the URI. And my Component works when Parameters are in the URI. But not when no Parameters are in it. The Parameters should optional.